# How to prevent cross-user related objects

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

How can I prevent cross-user related objects in multi-tenant shared-schema architecture?

For example:

- `ModelA` has foreign key `parent` to `ModelB`
- `instance_a.parent == instance_b`.

I can always check if `instance_A.owner == instance_b.owner` but that means an extra `SELECT` query for each `INSERT` query.

Is there any better way of validating related object?

My database is MySQL.

Comment: Having a composite key?

Answer (score 0):

Use select_related('model_B') while making query..
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related